# Does the .NET WebBrowser control support console.log?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a port of some Chrome extension to a better "managed" app - windows form/wpf, with embedded browser control. However, as part of my tracing/debugging flow, I was using the `console.log()` js feature in Chrome. However, I wonder, does the .NET browser support such a feature at all? And if it does, how does one view such content output via `console.log`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a TraceListener? Can you elaborate on why Console.Log isn't suitable, you need the web browser control to log out what exactly? Maybe Debug.WriteLine() is what you want and you view that in VS's Output Window

Comment: I wish to log things from the context of JS running in the browser control. So, I doubt Debug.WriteLine() would work...